# Nokia java application In-App Purchase wrong code in purchase completed callback

Tags: java-me, in-app-purchase, nokia, nokia-s40

I have a J2ME based application and i am new to IAP purchase. My scenario is after user purchase the application first time he can then use the application for 1 month after which he needs to repurchase it and similarly if he wants to further use it he has to purchase it after every month. So i have created a boolean variable and after every 30 days i make it false and then if user purchase the application through in-app purchase i can then make this variable true. so if after one month if user wants to further use it he can then repurchase it by pressing a button.in this button i am using the below code:

```
 int status = manager.purchaseProduct(PURCHASE_ID,
 IAPClientPaymentManager.FORCED_AUTOMATIC_RESTORATION);
 if (status != IAPClientPaymentManager.SUCCESS) {
 System.out.println(Messages.getPaymentError(status));
 return false;
     }
    return true;
```

and in callback....

```
public void purchaseCompleted(int status, String purchaseTicket) {
System.out.println("Purchase Completed : "+status+" "+purchaseTicket);
if (status == OK) {
System.out.println("ok");

} else {
System.out.println("Not ok");

}
}
```

but in call back i am getting a code : -35 ....i dont know why.....please note i am using nokia asha 303 simulator and when i use In-APP simulation for local sdk i get the response code ok. but when i use the nokia server i am getting an error code -35 in purchase completed.

Comment: Are you using Test server mode or Live mode? http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/in-app-purchase/implementing-in-app-purchase/testing-the-application.html

Comment: Did everything goes fine with Test server mode?

Comment: According to http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/_zip/GUID-57AF330C-5113-47B2-B134-48D6BAB1DC1D/constant-values.html#com.nokia.mid.payment.IAPClientPaymentListener.PMT_INSTR_FAILED -35 means GENERAL_HTTP_ERROR.

Comment: what does that means? when in product completed i am getting response code -16.

Comment: According o the link I provided on previous comment, error code -16 means INVALID_PRODUCT_DATA. Are you sure your content is correctly set?